# Android Menu doesn't appear

Tags: android, android-layout, menu

I'm currently working on Android apps, i'm still at the beginning. The last months I almost exclusively developed iOS-Apps as a software developer in my company, and now i have to do the same things in android.

My current problem is that i don't get a simple menu bar appeared on the screen. I made a dummy app with a Tab Activity and two Activities to switch between via the Tab Activity. Next thing I wanted to do is displaying a options menu in one of these embedded Activities.

This is how I made it (of course I read a few tutorials, and I think it has to be correct this way):

1. Created menu.xml in the /res/menu folder:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
   <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <item android:id="@+id/about"
             android:title="About" />
       <item android:id="@+id/help"
             android:title="Help" />
   </menu>
   ```
2. Added onCreateOptionsMenu in the selected Activity:

   ```
   package com.xitaso.androidlayouttest;

   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.view.Menu;
   import android.view.MenuInflater;

   public class SecondActivity extends Activity{

   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.second);
   }

   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {   
           MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();  
           menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);  
           return true;  
       } 
   }
   ```

Depending on various tutorials, this should be it. Is there anything I missed, do i have to add something to the Manifest-XML?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Drop a breakpoint in there, is it being called?

Comment: whats your code inside menu.xml? did you clean your project?

Comment: The Code seems to be fine to me.
If you post snapshot of your code here that would certainly help to track down the issue

Comment: The code in menu.xml is the one I pasted in 1.

Comment: yes, i know. it wasn't there before. Did you clean your project prior to test on emulator/device?

Comment: I tried it on both emulator (2.1) and device (galaxy nexus, 4.0.2), cleaned before running it...

Comment: if defined like this i don't think the options menu is supposed to show. On Android 4 without the (physical) menu button you'll get the "..." menu on screen. On devices with a (physical) menu button you'll have to press the menu button to see that menu. I recommend you take a look at these samples http://actionbarsherlock.com/samples.html which are basically for a different library but they work slightly modified for pure android as well.

Comment: same issue but looks no solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6640693/understanding-why-oncreateoptionsmenu-is-not-displaying-a-menu